# are typescript .d.ts file compile errors safe to ignore?

Tags: typescript

I am using VS 2013 community edition with the typescript plugin.

Are the compile time errors in the .d.ts files safe to ignore? All the .d.ts files were downloaded with the tsd tool.

for example for request, it needs the node.d.ts and form-data.d.ts files which i have not downloaded. Am I supposed to treewalk every definition file and get the referenced definition files too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I supposed to treewalk every definition file and get the referenced definition files too

the following should do this automatically:

```
npm install -g tsd@next
tsd install request -soar
```

> Are the compile time errors in the .d.ts files safe to ignore

Potentially yes. But if you do that then it becomes hard to know *what is safe to ignore and what isn't*. So try not to continue in the presence of errors.

Comment: ok, thanks. you need to add the 'r' option to resolve reference dependencies

Comment: of course.... now instead of 13 errors i had originally, i have 105 errors instead :( node.d.ts is throwing out many many errors